# como desactivar un input despues de dar clic en un boton

Tags: php, html5

Tengo un formulario con 2 botones: **guardar** (este funciona bien), y **buscar** (problema).

Cuando yo presiono mi botón **buscar** me busca todos los datos del cliente y los muestra dentro de la página en sus respectivo **input**.
Lo que necesito es que al momento en que yo eliga un cliente y pulse **buscar** me muestre los datos pero con los **input desactivados** (que no permita editarlos).

El problema es que como esta dentro del `<form>` cuando doy clic se desactiva enseguida el **input**, pero acto seguido me cargan los resultado de la busqueda y me vuelve a salir activado el **input**.

Lo que quiero es que al mostrar los resultados salgan desactivado los input.

```
<?php
include 'base/conexion.php';
include 'base/registrar_empleado.php';
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ejemplo</title>
  </head>

  <fieldset class="conductor mb-5">
    <h1 class="datos">DATOS PERSONALES</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <div class="form-group row container">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 etiquetas">NOMBRE</label>
        <div class="col-8 col-sm-2 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <select id="xa" name="xa" class="form-control xa" value="<?php echo $varnombres?>">
            <option>Seleccione</option>
            <?php
                $query1=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT em_id, em_nombre From empleados where em_estado=1");
                while ($nombres = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $nombres['em_id']?>"> <?php echo  ($nombres['em_nombre']) ?> </option>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
          </select>
          <span id="errorbuscar" class="error"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="boton" value="BUSCAR" onclick="return validar_empleado2(this.form)">BUSCAR</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row container b2">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-form-label etiquetas">CEDULA</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <input type="text" id="cedula" name="cedula" class="form-control input" onkeypress="return solonumeros(event)" value="<?php echo $varcedula ?>">
          <span id="errorcedula" class="error"></span>
        </div>
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-form-label etiquetas">NOMBRE</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="APELLIDOS-NOMBRES" class="form-control input" onkeypress="return sololetras(event)" value="<?php echo ($varnombre) ?>">
          <span id="errornombre" class="error"></span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row container b2">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-form-label etiquetas">CIUDAD</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <input type="text" id="ciudad" name="ciudad" class="form-control input" value="<?php echo utf8_encode($varciudad) ?>" onkeypress="return sololetras(event)">
          <span id="errorciudad" class="error"></span>
        </div>
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-form-label etiquetas">DOMICLIO</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <input type="text" id="domicilio" name="domicilio" class="form-control input" value="<?php echo utf8_encode($vardomicilio) ?>">
          <span id="errordomicilio" class="error"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </fieldset>
```

en el php uso:

```
<?php

include 'conexion.php';
$conexion = $conexion;

$xa = $_POST["xa"];
$cedula = $_POST["cedula"];
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$ciudad = $_POST["ciudad"];
$domicilio = $_POST["domicilio"];

if (isset($_POST["boton"])) {
    $VBoton = $_POST["boton"];
    if ($VBoton == "BUSCAR") {
        $sql2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT em.em_cedula,em.em_nombre,em.em_ciudad,em.em_domicilio");

        $res = ($sql2);
        while ($resul = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
            $varcedula = $resul[0];
            $varnombre = $resul[1];
            $varciudad = $resul[2];
            $vardomicilio = $resul[3];
```

en javascript lo tengo así:

```
function validar_empleado2(formulario) {
  if (formulario.xa.value == "Seleccione") {
    document.getElementById("errorbuscar").innerText = "seleccione el nombre";
    formulario.xa.focus();
    return false;
  }
  document.getElementById('ciudad').disabled = 'true';
}
```

Comment: Termina de poner el PHP que falta, tal como está ahora no sabemos lo que ocurre despues ni como muestras los datos para poderlos poner en disable

Comment: en el archivo html en los input la parte de value pongo una variable ($varcedula) la cual en el archivo php obtiene el valor del array de la consulta ( $varcedula = $resul[0];)  , lo que permite en mostrar los datos

Answer (score 0):

A modo de ejemplo, te dejo este snippet con una forma de setear atributos en los elementos. adáptalo a tu código y comenta si tienes alguna dificultad.

La idea es que al hacer click en el botón, modificas el atributo `disabled` del `input`.

```js
//Al hacer click en el botón, se ejecuta la función...
function validar_empleado2() {
  //A modo de ejemplo, enviamos un dato al value del input
  document.getElementById('cedula').setAttribute("value", "1234567890");
  //Seteamos el atributo disabled
  document.getElementById('cedula').setAttribute("disabled", "true");
}
```

```html
<button value="BUSCAR" onclick="validar_empleado2()">
  BUSCAR
</button>
<input type="text" class="datos" id="cedula" value="">
```

Comment: si funciona bien pero el problema radica que es formulario y por tal esta dentro de la etiqueta <form> y esto actualiza la pag y vuelve a estar activado el input , te suguiero que lo pruebes

Comment: Con `event.preventDefault()` evitas el comportamiento por defecto del formulario. O al finalizar la carga de la información en los `input` puedes ejecutar una función adicional que agregue el atributo a los `input`. Otra opción es usar `ajax` o `fetch` para realizar la búsqueda y así evitas que la pagina se recargue.